# Julia function without name and with double parenthesis

Tags: syntax, julia

This is a "beginning with Julia"-question.

I read some basic Julia function tutorials, but could
not yet find the sense of double parenthesis, like in
this example (from JuliaReinforcement RandomWalk1D):

```
function (env::RandomWalk1D)(action)
    env.pos = max(min(env.pos + env.actions[action], env.N), 1)
end
```

What does the double parenthesis (without function name??) mean here?
When and how is this function called?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you refer to the source of the package that can be found [here](https://github.com/JuliaReinforcementLearning/ReinforcementLearning.jl/blob/f97747923c6d7bbc5576f81664ed7b05a2ab8f1e/src/ReinforcementLearningEnvironments/src/environments/examples/RandomWalk1D.jl#L26).

This kind of definition creates a functor. See [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/#Function-like-objects) in the documentation for an explanation.

The idea is simple. You want to be able to call a value just like you would call a function. Here is a minimal example:

```
julia> struct A
           v
       end

julia> (x::A)() = x.v

julia> a = A(100)
A(100)

julia> a()
100
```

Note that in this example `a` is a value, but still you can call it with `a()` as if it were a function.

If something is not clear please comment and I can expand on it.

Comment: Great and clear! Thanks a lot! Also for the link to the documentation!!!